# Polish characters in utf-8 change after being saved to a textfile

Tags: python, utf-8, text-files, polish

The character `"\xc4\x86"` represents letter `"Ć"` but after executing this code:

```
string = "ABC\xc4\x86def"

with open("messagessemi.txt","w", encoding = "utf-8") as f:
    f.write(string)
```

the content of **messagessemi.txt** looks like this:

`ABCÄ†def`

What should I do to save the letters in a correct way? Thank you for any clues.

Comment: A [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case: `string.encode('latin1').decode('utf8')` returns `'ABCĆdef'`… Of course, `print(string)` shows `ABCÄdef`…

Comment: Written as `"ABC\xc4\x86def"` in Python, `\xc4` represents Unicode code point U+00C4 (LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH DIAERESIS).  and U+0086 (a control code).  To represent UTF-8, the data should be a byte string (type `bytes`) and not a Unicode string (type `str`).  Use `b'ABC\xc4\x86def'` for a byte string and write the binary data with `'wb'` and no encoding parameter, or use `.encode('latin1')` as previously mentioned to convert the Unicode codepoints 1:1 to bytes.  FYI, Latin-1 is encoded in the first 256 bytes of the Unicode standard U+0000 to U+00FF so it matches 1:1 with bytes.